# Find the Power sets of P[P{P(Φ)}]

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

My approach :
Null set contains itself only so number of elements is 1.
Or we can apply the direct formula of 2^n [where n is the number of elelments]
Now i got 
P{P(1)}
Applying the formula again
It becomes, 
P{2}=2²=4
But it was by the formula, 
Now i tried to write the sets and got like this, 
Let P(Φ)={Φ}
Then P[P(Φ)]= {Φ,{Φ}}
Here i got tge two sets but I can't figure out what will be the last 4 sets. 
Any way I convinced myself ,
P[P{P(Φ)}]={Φ,{Φ},{{Φ}},  {Φ,{Φ},{{Φ}} } }
I thought as each set contains itself 
But suddenly I relized that if it is so then
P[P(Φ)]= {Φ,{Φ}, {Φ,{Φ}} }
Then there will be three Power sets.

Comment: Number of elements of null set is actually zero

Comment: Your question is unclear, and would be made clearer if you could format your question using MathJax.  In particular, is Φ supposed to be a particular set?  or is it the emptyset?  In MathJax, you can type `$\emptyset$` to get $\emptyset$, or `$\Phi$` for $\Phi$.

Comment: Regarding notation, the typography of this post and the comment of @XanderHenderson led me to find a paragraph on wikipedia which points out that the empty set notation $\emptyset$ has nothing to do with the Greek letter Φ or $\Phi$, and is instead derived from a vowel in Norwegian and Danish https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_set#Notation

Comment: An [introduction to posting mathematical notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) using `MathJax` and $\LaTeX$.

Answer (score 2):

Let us save some braces

$$P(\phi)=\{\phi\}=A$$

$$ P(P(\phi))=P(A)=\{\phi, A\}=B$$

$$ P(P(P(\phi))) =P(B)=\{\phi, \{A\} , \{\phi\},B\}$$

Comment: That's a beautifully crafted answer.. I wanted to cross check my answer with another I'd find online and lo! This is great...

Answer (score 0):

$\emptyset$ has no elements and only itself, i.e. $\emptyset$, as subset. Hence $$P(\emptyset)=\{\emptyset\}.$$

$\{\emptyset\}$ has one element $\emptyset$, hence two subsets $\emptyset$ and $\{\emptyset\}$ itself. Hence $$P(P(\emptyset))=\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}.$$

$\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$ has two elements $\emptyset$ and $\{\emptyset\}$, hence has four subsets $\emptyset$ and $\{\emptyset\}$ and $\{\{\emptyset\}\}$  and $\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$ itself. Hence
$$ P(P(P(\emptyset)))=\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\},\{\{\emptyset\}\},\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}\}.$$
This gets funny if one uses $\{\}$ as notation for the emptyset:
$ \{\{\},\{\{\}\},\{\{\{\}\}\},\{\{\},\{\{\}\}\}\}$.